# Issue retrieving contents through Google Cal API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Working on a WP plugin.  It's end purpose is to serve as an inspection calendar for home inspectors.  We're working with a Google Calendar that is already loaded full of events.

I am authenticating via Oauth2 & a Service account.  The plugin needs only to access the inspection company's data, no other private user data.

Here's the code:

```
    // Set up identity ------------------------------------.
    $client_email = "XXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    $private_key = file_get_contents( EC_INSPECT_CAL_INC . "/HE_Web_1.p12" );
    $scope = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly","https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds" ];
    $credentials = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        $scope,
        $private_key
    );


    // Build Config Obj ------------------------------------.
    $config = new \Google_Config();
    $config->setClassConfig('Google_Cache_File', array('directory' => EC_INSPECT_CAL_INC . '/tmp/cache'));


    // Instantiate Client Connection ------------------------.
    $client = new \Google_Client( $config );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials( $credentials );
    if( $client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired() )
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();

    $service            = new \Google_Service_Calendar( $client );
    $calendarList       = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

    while( true )
    {

        foreach( $calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry )
        {

            // get events 
            $events = $service->events->listEvents( $calendarListEntry->id );

            foreach( $events->getItems() as $event )
                        echo "-----".$event->getSummary() . "<br>";

        }


        $pageToken      = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
        if( !$pageToken ) break;


        $optParams      = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $calendarList   = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);

    }
}
```

If I var_dump the following:

```
var_dump( $service->calendarList->listCalendarList() );
```

It results in:

```
array(0) { }
```

My wife would like me to stop cursing in front of the dogs, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm overlooking. The calendar is loaded with content, and I (AFAIK) am authenticating ... So where's the goods??

Comment: First of all CalendarList does not exist for a service account. Second of all you probably want to be listing events for which you should use events.list(). Third of all you will need to specify the ID of the calendar you want to access and you will need to make sure the service account has access to that calendar (you can do that by sharing the calendar with the service account in the web ui).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, Luc.  I did share a test calendar, over the weekend, and can see events.